# Drop down menu always displays 1st option after page processing instead of processed option, Node JS, Express-Handlebars

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars, hbs

When I select an option and click the submit button, the view is rendered again, the query is fine but instead of the drop down menu displaying the submitted option, it's actually always displaying the 1st option.

Here's all the code from node js,

```
let dsPhim=[];
let dsPC=[];

class lichChieu{
   // GET[]/lichchieu/them
    async themLichChieu(req,res){
        try {
            const queryPhim = 'SELECT * FROM Phim WHERE hienThi=1 AND trangThai=1';
            const queryPC = 'SELECT * FROM PhongChieu WHERE trangThai=1';
    
            connection.query(queryPhim,(err,resultsPhim)=>{

                dsPhim=resultsPhim;
                connection.query(queryPC,(err,resultPC)=>{
                    dsPC=resultPC;
                    res.render('showtimes/themLichChieu', {
                        title: 'Thêm Lịch Chiếu Phim',
                        listPhim: dsPhim,
                        listPC: dsPC
                    });
                })
            })
            
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Lỗi', err.message);
        }
                
    }
    // POST[]/lichchieu/them/luu
    async luuLichChieu(req, res) {  
        let notificationErr=[];
        let notificationSuccess=[];      
        const ngayChieu = req.body.ngayChieu;
        const caChieu = req.body.caChieu;
        const giaPhim = req.body.giaPhim;
        const idPhongChieu = req.body.idPhongChieu;
        const idPhim = req.body.idPhim;
        
        const checkQuery=`SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM lichchieu WHERE caChieu=? and ngayChieu=? and idPhongChieu=?`;
        const checkValues=[caChieu,ngayChieu,idPhongChieu];
        

        connection.query(checkQuery,checkValues,(errCheck,checkResult)=>{
            if(checkResult[0].count>0){
                notificationErr.push({err:'Ca chiếu trong ngày này đã có lịch chiếu'});
                res.render('showtimes/themLichChieu', {
                    title: 'Thêm Lịch Chiếu Phim',
                    listPhim:dsPhim,
                    listPC:dsPC,
                    notificationErr:notificationErr,
                    ngayChieu: req.body.ngayChieu,
                    caChieu: req.body.caChieu,
                    giaPhim: req.body.giaPhim,
                    idPhongChieu: req.body.idPhongChieu,
                    idPhim: req.body.idPhim,
                }); 
             

            }else{
                const insertQuery = `INSERT INTO LichChieu (ngayChieu, caChieu, giaPhim, ngayThem, hienThi, idPhongChieu, idPhim)
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`;

                const insertValues = [
                    ngayChieu,
                    caChieu,
                    giaPhim,
                    new Date(),
                    1, 
                    idPhongChieu,
                    idPhim
                ];                
            
                connection.query(insertQuery, insertValues, (err, results) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error('Lỗi', err.message);
                        notificationErr.push({err: err.message});
                        res.render('showtimes/themLichChieu', {
                            title: 'Thêm Lịch Chiếu Phim',
                            listPhim:dsPhim,
                            listPC:dsPC,
                            notificationErr:notificationErr,
                            ngayChieu: req.body.ngayChieu,
                            caChieu: req.body.caChieu,
                            giaPhim: req.body.giaPhim,
                            idPhongChieu: req.body.idPhongChieu,
                            idPhim: req.body.idPhim,
                        }); 
                        
                    } else {
                        notificationSuccess.push({success:"Thêm lịch chiếu thành công"})
                        res.render('showtimes/themLichChieu', {
                            title: 'Thêm Lịch Chiếu Phim',
                            notificationSuccess: notificationSuccess,
                            listPhim:dsPhim,
                            listPC:dsPC,
                            ngayChieu: req.body.ngayChieu,
                            caChieu: req.body.caChieu,
                            giaPhim: req.body.giaPhim,
                            idPhongChieu: req.body.idPhongChieu,
                            idPhim: req.body.idPhim,
                        });     
                         
                               
                     }
                     const updateQuery=`UPDATE Phim SET trangThai=2 WHERE idPhim=?`;
                     const idPhim=[req.body.idPhim];
                     connection.query(updateQuery,[idPhim],(errUpdate,updateResults)=>{
                        if(errUpdate){
                            console.error('Lỗi update trạng thái phim',errUpdate.message)
                            return;
                        }
                        console.log('Cập nhật trạng thái phim thành công')
                     })



                });

            }
        })
    }
```

And this is the code to import helper handlebar

```
  handlebars.engine({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    extname: '.hbs',
    layoutsDir: __dirname + '\\src\\views\\layouts\\',
    partialsDir: __dirname + '\\src\\views\\',
    helpers: {
      sum: (a, b) => a + b,
      formatDate:(date) => moment(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY'),
      paginate: paginateHelper.createPagination,
      formatCurrency: (number, currencyCode) => {
        const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('vi-VN', {
          style: 'currency',
          currency: currencyCode,
        });
        return formatter.format(number);
      },
      eq(val1, val2, options) {
        return val1 === val2 ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
      },

    },
  })
);
```

This is the form submit

```
<form action="/lichchieu/them/luu" method="POST" class="container-form-add mx-auto" style="max-width: 900px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label" for="idPhim">Tên Phim</label>
                <select id="idPhim" name="idPhim" class="form-control">
                    {{#each listPhim}}
                        <option name="{{this.idPhim}}" value="{{this.idPhim}}" {{#eq this.idPhim @root.idPhim}}selected{{/eq}}>{{this.tenPhim}}</option>
                    {{/each}}
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label" for="idPhongChieu">Phòng chiếu</label>
                <select id="idPhongChieu" value="idPhongChieu" name="idPhongChieu" class="form-control">
                    {{#each listPC}}
                    <option name="{{this.idPhongChieu}}" value="{{this.idPhongChieu}}" >{{this.tenPhongChieu}}</option>                        
                    {{/each}}
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label" for="caChieu">Ca Chiếu</label>
                <select id="caChieu" name="caChieu" value="{{caChieu}}" class="form-control">
                    <option name="" value="Ca 1: 8-10h">Ca 1: 8-10h</option>
                    <option name="" value="Ca 2: 13h-15h">Ca 2: 13h-15h</option>
                    <option name="" value="Ca 3: 16-19h30">Ca 3: 16-19h30</option>
                    <option name="" value="Ca 4: 20-23h">Ca 4: 20-23h</option>                        

                </select>
            </div>                              
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label" for="showDate">Ngày chiếu</label>
                <input class="form-control" value="{{ngayChieu}}" name="ngayChieu" required name="ngayChieu" id="ngayChieu" type="date" data-date="" data-date-format="DD MMMM YYYY"  aria-describedby="helpId" />
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label" for="price">Giá phim</label>
                <input class="form-control" value="{{giaPhim}}" required type="number" name="giaPhim" id="giaPhim" aria-describedby="helpId" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="padding: 10px; min-width: 400px; font-weight: bold; margin: 10px;">Thêm mới</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want when I first render this view and select an item from the drop-down list and submit the form to render the view again, that the item that I have submitted will show on the drop-drown list as selected, not the default item. Thank you for helping me, have a great day.

Comment: Are you rendering the select menu again once the form has been submitted to the server with a POST request?

Comment: Yes, at first i render views to select the menu and submit to render the views again (with method POST). But the option render views again always display at 1st option not the option that i have selected before

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank u, i have update all the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add the `selected` attribute to the option that corresponds to the value of `idPhim` that the user has sent to your server in the body of the POST request.

The first thing we would need is a custom [Handlebars helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/block-helpers.html#block-helpers) that will allow us to compare two values and render a branch of template *only if* those values are equal. Where exactly this helper should go will depend on your configuration and initialization of [express-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars), but it would look something like this:

```
helpers: {
  eq(val1, val2, options) {
    return val1 === val2 ? options.fn(this) : options.inverse(this);
  }
}
```

Next, we will update our template to make use of this new helper. It looks from your post that we already have the submitted value as `idPhim` in our template data. What we need to be careful of is avoiding confusion between the `idPhim` that belongs to the current object in our `listPhim` iteration and the `idPhim` on the root template data object that was assigned the value of `req.body.idPhim`. To access the latter, we could use a [path prefix](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#changing-the-context), as in `../idPhim`, to step-up a context level; but, in this case, I will use the [@root data-variable](https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/data-variables.html#root), because I think it is more explicit and therefore will help clarify:

```
<option
  name="{{this.idPhim}}"
  value="{{this.idPhim}}"
  {{#eq this.idPhim @root.idPhim}}selected{{/eq}}
>{{this.tenPhim}}</option>
```

With this addition to our template, the item in `listPhim` whose `idPhim` is equal to `@root.idPhim` will have the `selected` attribute added to its `<option>` output, thereby making it the selected value when the page is rendered by the user's web browser.

Comment: Thank u sir. I tried, but it didn't work

Comment: @Jin You will need to provide a little more information if we are to troubleshoot this. Did you get an error? Are you sure that the submitted value is available as `req.body.idPhim`? Can you log which values are being used to call the `eq` helper?

Comment: I have log the values are used to call the eq, the value is correct with the option that i have selected. I'm still trying to find a solution. Anyway thank for your attention and your solution sir, I really appreciate about that.

Comment: @Jin It might be wise to check the _types_ of the args to `eq` as well. It is possible that each `listPhim`'s object has an `idPhim` that is a `number`, but the value of `req.body.idPhim` is a `string`.

Comment: It's work.. thank u very very much  sir . And is eq can use to check the value String?

Comment: @Jin The way we have written the `eq` helper, it uses the `===` JavaScript operator. This requires both values to have the same _type_ in order to be considered equal - 1 and 1 are equal, 1 and "1" are not.

Comment: Thank for your help, i really appreciate about that. Have a good day sir 

Comment: @Jin You're very welcome. I hope you have a good day as well.